# change view of calendar web part

Tags: 2010, calendar, filter

i have a calendar with a custom column called discipline.  This is a master calendar that all disciplines will use.  I've added the calendar web part to a sub page and i need to filter the calendar based on the discipline column.  I was thinking of using the query string (see below) and passing in the discipline name and then filtering but im stuck as to how i would pass the query string value to the web part.  Any ideas?

```
http://somedomanin/Project_Support_Team/Sharing%20Excellence/default.aspx?discipline=structures
http://somedomanin/Project_Support_Team/Sharing%20Excellence/default.aspx?discipline=buildings
```

The only other option i can think of is adding many calendar web parts to the page and setting up an audience based on the users discipline value in UPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SharePoint Calendar web part cannot be filtered dynamically and it cannot be filtered by custom fields. This site offers a custom web part that can take query parameters. I have not tested it, but it looks promising:

https://aasoftech.sharepoint.com/Products/Lists/How%20to%20Filter%20SharePoint%20Calendar%20Dynamically/AllItems.aspx